# PHP losing variable after an error message is called

Tags: php, die

I am losing my varible $user once I call my error function and include the footer file. I use the $user function in my footer to display some information, but when I went to var_dump it, it just says null. Note, I am using a database framework that someone created, so the query might look weird, but it is 100% functional and secured.

This is in my /includes/functions file:

```
$user_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$_COOKIE[id]' LIMIT 1");
$user = $db->getArray($user_query);

function error($input){

            echo '<div id="error_box"><h1>Ooops!</h1><br>
             '.$input.'<br /><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"><b>Back to previous page.</b></a></div>';

   require_once('./layout/footer.php');
   die;

}
```

and my /layout/footer.php file is:

```
         if (!empty($user['active'])){

           //info here

         }
         else {

            //info here

            var_dump($user);

         }
```

Comment: That's not 100% secured, but those bash comments will come .. ;) .. and whats wrong with this code? It's correct that the `error` function doesn't know the `$user` variable, it's not in the scope of `error`

Comment: Read up on PHP variable scope. Variables declared outside a function are not automatically visible inside it.

Comment: Thank you!

I left out some of the script that does security on it and edited it a little bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$user` is out of scope in `error()`. A quick fix is to [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) it. So:

```
function error($input){
   global $user;
   // ...
}
```

It may be worth reading up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in general.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the variable scope, it helped, fixed now!